# Issue with Wacom Intuos S and Blender grease pencil blotching at end of stroke

Tags: grease-pencil

[image: Some examples of the blotching]

Just setup my new Wacom Intuos S and am getting weird blotching at the end of strokes - Does not seem to happen if dynamic pressure is disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be subconsciously lifting the pen in anticipation of the end of the stroke and then slightly depressing it again.

Comment: Not familiar with the technology in these, but does it have something to do with lifting your palm?

Comment: Did you update to the latest drivers ? Not the one shipped with the hardware ?

Comment: @MartyFouts I do a very consistent stroke and make sure to specifically lift off pressure evenly, so I am pretty sure it's a software issue

Comment: @Gorgious Yeah, seems like latest drivers are installed